# for loop list incrementation

Tags: python, for-loop

In order to find multiples of 3 under 1000, I used this method:

```
a=[]
import itertools
for x in itertools.count():
    while x<1000:
        if x%3==0:
            a.append[x]
print(a)
```

I'm a beginner, please help me find the error.

Comment: The only error I see right now is that there is no indentation. What does the program do and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Do you know about `range`'s 3rd argument?

Comment: Now I do see one: `append[x]`. `append` is a function, so its arguments should be in parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you coding in Python 3 ?

You are missing indentation mostly and usage of function depends on the version of Python you are using and also there are different solutions to how you can handle the iterations , which may differ to your style. I also want to point out that append method needs parentheses instead of brackets.

However i tried not to modify your code much.
You can check it on the online editor below.

https://repl.it/@Umbreon1/SpiffyAshamedPdf

```
import itertools
a=[]
upperLimit=1000
for x in itertools.islice(itertools.count(0),upperLimit + 1):
    if x%3 == 0:
        a.append(x)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply

```
a = list(range(0, 1000, 3))
```

or even

```
a = range(0, 1000, 3)
```

in Python 2?